# Zendesk api v2 python to static zendesk ticket

Tags: python, zendesk, zendesk-api

Help,
I used zendesk api v2 python to static zendesk ticket and compare with zendesk custom report but have different result.

custom start  December 14, 2017 end December 15, 2017 but have two different results:

custom 161 new ticket but api code return 84 ticket only.
I try other different custom report, and have similar issues

What is wrong with my case?
Thanks for help

```
r = requests.get('https://mydomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/search.json?query=type:ticket%20created%3E2017-12-14T00:00:00Z%20created%3C2017-12-15T00:00:00Z&page=1&sort_by=created_at&sort_order=desc',auth=('myauth', 'mypass'))
print json.dumps(r.json(), sort_keys=True, indent=10)
```

Comment: also give the json response, there is chance there is pagination happening for results, which means you will need to use that as input for the next query to get all values.

Comment: api return "count": 84 but custom 161 . I knows results will pagination if(count>100)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem in your query is:

```
created%3E2017-12-14T00:00:00Z%20created%3C2017-12-15T00:00:00Z
```

It seems that you querying from the midnight of December 14th to the midnight of December 15th, so the result set should return only the tickets from December 14th.

I had a look at [Zendesk API Search documentation](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/search) and I would say that it should be enough to encode:

```
created>2017-12-14T00:00:00Z created<2017-12-16T00:00:00Z
```

instead:

```
created%3E2017-12-14T00:00:00Z%20created%3C2017-12-16T00:00:00Z
```

You can find some specific [python examples](https://help.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/229136927#python) and this [pagination doc](https://help.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/229489028). Your code should look like:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import requests

results = [] # Empty list store paginated results    
credentials = 'your_zendesk_email', 'your_zendesk_password'
session = requests.Session()
session.auth = credentials

params = {
    'query': 'type:ticket created>2017-12-14T00:00:00Z created<2017-12-16T00:00:00Z',
    'sort_by': 'created_at',
    'sort_order': 'desc'
}

url = 'https://your_subdomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/search.json?' + urlencode(params)

while url:
    response = session.get(url)
    data = response.json()
    results += data['results']
    url = data['next_page'] # At the last page, the API should return false

print json.dumps(results.json(), sort_keys=True, indent=10)
```